# Inegrating Kendo UI for jQuery Scheduler into Angular 4.x

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

So I'm integrating the jQuery scheduler in our Angular 4.x app and managing to provide data to and from DB through various means.

I have customised event edit HTML and within that a dropdownlist which fires a normal javascript... how can I access the current event at this point? I want to change variables within the model where necessary and for it to reflect in the html editor (since it's MVVM)? I tried accessing through the datasource.data.events[whatever] and then performing a sync() and this updates the data but closes the editor window which I need to remain open............any other ideas as to how to achieve this please?

Comment: So you want to change values while the editor is open? Before the user clicked on OK or Cancel?

Comment: Hi Shai, Yes. I want to gain access to the current event object the editor references (again since it's MVVM then changing the underlying, bound object properties would affect the relevant fields on the display)...any suggestions?